# Redirection not working in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, permissions

I have an application and its working locally perfect.

on production, all pages are fine which haven't redirection.

- Its connected with database because data showing on list pages
- I have checked controllers/models for starting and ending code (spaces removed and closing PHP tag removed)
- I checked permissions (all folders are 755 and tmp is 777)
- I updated debug value to 2,3 but not showing any thing
- I checked using PR few variables and in view source it shows few spaces (didn't get any clue that from where the spaces are embedding)
- Also, I have uploaded fresh copy of lib/Cake
- One another project in same version of Cake is already deployed and working perfectly (Prefix changed for both projects)

On redirection, it shows a blank page. I checked view source of this blank page and it contains 32 spaces.

Any Clue why its happening or from where I need to remove these spaces?

Comment: Such questions that are likely to require a lot of back and forth are usually not suited for SO, you'd probably be better off asking this for example in the google group where lengthy discussions are no problem. Anyways, what exactly does "_on redirect_" mean? Does the blank page show after the redirect occoured, ie on the target page, or does the blank page show instead of the redirect happening, ie the response that should trigger the redirect contains the whitespace? And how exactly are you redirecting (code wise)?

Comment: 1st, I am sorry for posting this question here. 
2nd, thanks for your reply.

well, blank page shows where $this->redirect('/'); written.
Here i want that after interacting with db, go to home page. but not going. I also changed to $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'records'));

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have found my mistake. Problem was due to IDE, it appends spaces at end of the file while locally it were correct. :)

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked the notification about your first reply. You might want to add the solution as an actual answer with some details about your specific IDE, the functionality that causes the additional spaces, how to disable it, and finally accept the answer so that the question appears resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed.

Because it was issue of IDE.

I am using sublime but same Dreamweaver have same issue.

For Sublime, we can load a package : https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces

For Dreamweaver, we need to do manually by search and replace. 
for more details : http://www.jaredstenquist.com/2009/02/13/removing-extra-linebreaks-and-spaces-in-dreamweaver/

Thanks